# What column type should I use to store values between 0 and 1 (say up to 5 decimal places) in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

It is most important that it be accurate, but also it should take the least disk space possible.

Answer (score 9):

You would need a `DECIMAL(6,5)` to store a number from 0 to 1 with 5 decimal places.

The declaration syntax for a DECIMAL column is DECIMAL(M,D). The ranges of values for the arguments in MySQL 5.1 are as follows:

- M is the maximum number of digits (the precision). It has a range of 1 to 65.
- D is the number of digits to the right of the decimal point (the scale). It has a range of 0 to 30 and must be no larger than M.

Comment: I think "no larger" means you can have DECIMAL (5,5).

Comment: @yu_sha, DECIMAL(5,5) has a range of .0 - .999... (no digits left of the decimal point), so that won't cut it in this case if 1 has to be included.

Comment: Good point. Unfortunately, Decimal(6,5) takes 4 bytes (integer and float parts are stored separately). Might as well use float.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-requirements.html), in MySQL 5.0.3

- DECIMAL(5,5) or DECIMAL (6,6) should take 3 bytes.
- DECIMAL(4,4) 2 bytes.

If you need to store values from 0 to 1 inclusive, you might be tempted to use DECIMAL(6,5). But that occupies 4 bytes as integer and float parts are stored separately and you need one byte for integer and three for 5 decimal digits. And if you have 4 bytes you might as well use FLOAT.

Before MySql 5 DECIMALs were stored as strings and the most efficient way was to store SMALLINT or MEDIUMINT (2 or 3 bytes) and manually divide it by 10000 or 1000000 respectively.

Comment: If 1 is exclusive (i.e. 0 <= your data <  1) then DECIMAL(5,5) is ok; if 1 is inclusive (i.e. 0 <= your data <= 1) then DECIMAL(6,5) is needed.

Comment: Good point. Unfortunately, Decimal(6,5) takes 4 bytes (integer and float parts are stored separately). Might as well use float.